# React Native iOS - Modal not showing on simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

As the title says, the modal is not showing on iOS simulators and generated IPA files. But it works fine on Android simulators. Did i miss any code-specific to iOS? Stuck at this for a while.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: please let me see the code..

Comment: i am quite sure that you are messing up with code soewhere.. so show us code then only we can help you

Comment: Try setting transparent to false

Comment: tried it. didnt work

Comment: any more idea..?

Comment: put modal under other views, except the wrapping view. and also if it won't work, try tweaking your styles. flexes.

Answer (score 1):

Without any Code or any version number is hard to help you.
But I'm still gonna give you my 2 cents.
There have been a lot of issues with Modal in react versions from 0.40 to 0.44 at least.
It could have more issues but I don't know.
So trying to search the needle in the haystack.

(Pay attention that with the lack of info about the problem/ambient there isn't much anyone can do to help you).

1- If you have any alert or modal open, or recently closed before trying to open this modal, the modal won't show. To see if you have this issue, clean any modal and alert, and try to render your app with only this view.

2- It could be a problem with [ScrollView](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17002)

3- Did you tried to build a release file for ios and install on a device to see if still happens?  [issue here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12747)

4-I think I saw a few issue's there were about problems between modal and navigation systems. so i advise you to search there too.

5-It could be something else, I advise to do a deep search on react-native issues and try to see if someone else is experiencing this issue.

For more help please edit your question and put more info, and I will edit my answer, and if by any chance any of this options work, please put on the commentary which one work to give a forther explanation.

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with modals not showing up on iOS but working fine on Android in React Native, there are a few things you can check to troubleshoot the issue:

Check for Platform-Specific Code: Ensure that you haven't written any platform-specific code that might be causing the issue. React Native allows you to write platform-specific code using Platform.OS === 'ios' or Platform.OS === 'android' conditionals. Make sure that any iOS-specific code related to modals is correctly implemented.

Check for Modal Props: React Native's Modal component has some props that might behave differently on iOS and Android. For example, the transparent prop might behave differently on each platform. Check if any props you're using with the Modal component are causing the issue.

Check for Styling Issues: Sometimes, styling issues can cause components to behave differently on different platforms. Check if there are any styles applied to the Modal component or its parent components that might be affecting its visibility on iOS.

Check for Known Issues: Search for any known issues related to modals in the version of React Native you're using. Sometimes, there are platform-specific bugs or limitations that might cause unexpected behavior.

Check Xcode Logs: If you're testing on an iOS simulator, check the Xcode logs for any errors or warnings related to the modal. This might give you more insight into what's causing the issue.

Check for External Libraries: If you're using any third-party libraries that might be interacting with modals or the navigation stack, make sure they are compatible with both iOS and Android.

Check for Permission Issues: If your modal requires any special permissions (e.g., camera access, location access), make sure you've correctly handled permissions on both iOS and Android.

Check for Device-Specific Issues: If the modal works on some iOS devices but not others, or if it works on a physical device but not the simulator, there might be device-specific issues that need to be addressed.

By systematically checking these areas, you can narrow down the cause of the issue and hopefully resolve the problem with your modal not showing up on iOS.

Comment: Posting AI-generated answers is [forbidden on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).